# RIAK Cluster across AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, replication, high-availability, riak

I have an application hosted in AWS, where the application's data is stored in RIAK KV cluster; there are 5 nodes forms this cluster.

To meet high demand and availability constrains, i would like to replicate the complete setup in another AWS region (as active-active), where yet another RIAK KV cluster will be created with upto 5 node.

Now the question is, **How do i sync the data between these 2 RIAK cluster which are running in 2 different AWS regions?**

Since the opensource/commercial version of RIAK KV does not provide multi region clustering capability, How do i sync data between these clusters?

Answer (score 1):

The Enterprise version of Riak KV has multi-cluster/datacenter replication built in (as you note in your question). This form of replication does some pretty clever things to ensure that data copied to both clusters remains in synch when updated as well as recovering from things like data center failure and split brain conditions.

If you want to roll your own replication there are quite a few ways that you might approach it including:

- Dual write - have your application send writes to both clusters in parallel;
- Post-commit hooks (http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/latest/developing/usage/commit-hooks/) - after date gets written to one cluster successfully use a post-commit hook to replicate the write to the other cluster

The primary weakness of these solutions is that you still need to figure out how to keep data in synch across the clusters under failure conditions.

I know that there are more than a handful of Riak KV open source users who have rolled various in house replication mechanisms so hopefully one of them will chime in with what they have done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The post commit hook is something i might explore.